# can't use passed prop in child's method:{} vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I pass the array to child as prop. And trying to use it in google map method. But when I use it inside initMap: function the array being empty.

**in parent**

```
<div class="mapWrap">
    <mapping :articles="filterArticles" />
</div>

computed: {
  filterArticles(){
   let api = this.$store.getters.articles;

   let filteredStates = api.filter((article) => {
       return (this.keyword.length === 0 || article.address.includes(this.keyword)) &&
       (this.regions.length === 0 || this.regions.includes(article.region)) &&
       (this.rooms.length === 0 || this.rooms.includes(article.rooms1)) &&
       (this.city.length === 0 || this.city.includes(article.city))
   });

   return filteredStates;
  },
}
```

**in child**

```
props: {
    articles: {
        type:Array
    },
},
name:"mapping",
data(){
    return {
        marker:[],
    }
},
mounted(){
    this.initMap();
},
methods: {
    initMap: function() {
        var mapOptions = {
            mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.652832, 139.839478),
            zoom: 10
        };

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

        var articles = this.articles;
        console.log(articles);


    },
},
```

The way I am doing it wrong? Because prop has the items but when I put it inside the initMap method, it starts being empty...

Comment: For debugging purposes have you tried creating a data array in the parent, having the computed property update that, and then passing that data property instead?

Comment: What happens if you just `console.log(this.articles)` in the `created()` or `beforeCreate()` hook? Also, you can try `initMap: () => { ...  }` because the `this` inside the function may refer to the function itself...

Comment: @Kokodoko `created()` is give nothing. and `beforeCreate` is gives undefined... by the way... what do you mean by `iniMap: () => { ... }`

Comment: @MichaelPaccione I tried that, there is no effect on the initMap, it's still empty.

Comment: I mean replacing `initMap : function() {}` with `initMap: () => {}` to keep the same scope. But, you should be able to log the array. Are you sure `articles` has content? You can test that by placing a `console.log` in the compute function, or by installing the React Developer Extension. That allows you to inspect your component and see all variables: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en

Comment: oh sorry, I already done that. no effects. yes I am sure articles has content.. you can check it https://imgur.com/a/VovfVqV and marker has "0" because when I put the `articles`  inside initmap it start being empty @Kokodoko

Comment: @parabellum seems that when your mapping component is mounted it doesn't get any value...can you please add a default to your props `articles: {
        type:Array, default: () => []
    },`

Comment: If anything, the docs say to NOT use arrow functions: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#methods because the change the scope of "this". Ideally, you can just write `initMap () {}` which will work if you have Webpack / Vue CLI running. Not sure if that will fix the issue though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to trace the code and from what you have, it will work in most cases EXCEPT if the data that you have fetched using `this.$store.getters.articles` is async. Ideally, you should not be relying on the child component's `mount` event because it can get mounted way before you can display any data. To verify that, you can add a `console.log(this.articles)` inside the `mounted` hook and see that it's most likely empty.

What I suggest you do is, given that in the parent component you have `articles` as a computed property (which is reactive), you should also call the `initMap` inside the child every time the prop `articles` changes. The easiest way to do just that is with a watcher inside the child component:

```
watch: {
  articles () {
    this.initMap()
  }
}
```

Comment: yes, you are right. it's good to learn new things. thanks to you :) fixed the problem.